# How (or at least when) can I play Fifa Online 3 on the US server?

Tags: fifa-online-3

I have been having troubles trying to play Fifa Online 3 lately. I open Garena Plus and only shows he 'Perfect World 2' icon, and I got my beta key and everything is just that I can't (or doesn't show) the FO3 icon.

Does anyone know why or what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got from Garena Customer Service in response to the issue:

1. Open up your Garena Plus Messengers:
2. Go to the Wheel like icon located at the bottom left hand side
3. Go to the Region Tab
4. Change your Region to Singapore
5. Relog to your account and click on the the game in which you would want to play